# Get the mean of specific rows and store it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, rating

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
   userId     id      rating
   1          110     1.0
   2          141     3.0
   2          260     4.5
   2          1092    2.5
   3          223     4.0
```

I have a list of all the userIds, stored in users_list.

#### It is very long (1M rows), and I'm trying to get the mean rating per user and store it either:

- In the same users_list as before, but as a pair

  - Like [[userId1, meanRating], [userId2, meanRating], ...]
- As a feature in the DataFrame, so each row has the mean rating of that specific user (I can remove all rows except 1 per user)

I can get the mean rating with `df.loc[df['userId'] == users_list[someId]]['rating'].mean()`, but if I try to store it somewhere, I get the error that I'm trying to set values on a copy.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: `df.groupby('userId')['rating'].mean()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer with two options:

If you want have your original dataframe with a mean column

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('userId')['rating'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'rating':'mean'}), on='userId')

   userId    id  rating      mean
0       1   110     1.0  1.000000
1       2   141     3.0  3.333333
2       2   260     4.5  3.333333
3       2  1092     2.5  3.333333
4       3   223     4.0  4.000000
```

If you want a new dataframe with only userID and mean

```
df = df.groupby('userId')['rating'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'rating':'mean'})

   userId      mean
0       1  1.000000
1       2  3.333333
2       3  4.000000
```